# TCP sequence number tricks on split-TCP

Tags: networking, tcp, network-programming

I want to build such a system, there are 3 nodes, A, B and C A and B establish a TCP connection, then A tell C the ports, sequence number (seq_no)and Acknowlegement sequence number(ack_seq_no). Then C sends packet to B (C and A share the same IP but they are far away from each other, e.g, C spoof IP of A)

if B never sends data packets to IP(A)(only ACK), C can send packets to B with correct seq_no and ack_seq_no but sometimes if B send a data packet P1to IP(A),

1 A immediately send ACK for the data packet P1 to B, and A tell C the new ack_seq_no. But there is a delay between A and C, so before C knows the new ack_seq_no C may send some data packets(with spoofed IP(A)) to B with obsolete ack_seq_no.

my first question is: what will C behave when it receives a data packet with obsolete ack_seq_no

2 if I delay the ACK for p1 from A to B, I let A tell C first, and then sends the ACK for p1. there are 2 questions:

1) since B is waiting for the ACK of p1 from A, it may retransmit the packet p1, how to increase the retransmission timeout? if each time A reply with the ACK with such a delay, the timeout will be naturally increased, then it is not a problem?

2) if C sends data packets to B(with IP of A) before the ACK(for p1) from A to B. This means the data packets are with updated ack_seq_no, but B doesn't know whether its new ack_seq_no has been known by A or not(coz ACK hasn't arrived yet), so it may regard the ACK is piggybacked over the data packets? then how will B deal with the late ACK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If an obsolete ACK is received, the ACK will be ignored (it's assumed to be an old packet that was delayed). Every ACK acknowledges everything leading up to it (I'm assuming you're not sending selective ACKs).
2. The sender should adjust its retransmission timeouts based on the acknowledgement response times.
3. B can't tell the difference between an ACK from A or C. As far as it's concerned, this is the same as question #1 -- the late ACK will be ignored.

Comment: for 1) it is not obsolete ACK, it is a data packet with obsolete `ack_seq_no`, so you mean the data packet will be ignored?

Comment: for 2), you mean if I delay the ACK for p1 from A to B, then the B will adjust its retransmission timeout, and the retransmission only happen at the beginning, and it will not happend from later on. This means my delay strategy will work fine!

Comment: The data in the packet will be processed if its sequence number is higher than what has already been received. The acknowledgement will be ignored if it is lower than a previously received acknowledgement.

Comment: for 3) the packet that B receives from C is a data packet, not an ACK, but the data packet are with a updated `ack_seq_no`, so you mean the B will regard the data packet from C as an ACK piggybacking data (or in another way, a data packet piggybacking ACK)

Comment: All packets (except the initial SYN) are ACKs, some also contain data. The receiver processes the acknowledgement number and the data independently.

Comment: maybe you are not clear, let me give an example : if B send a packet of 10 bytes(seq= 10, ack_seq=100) to A, A will respond an ACK(seq=100, ack_seq=20), but C sends a data packet(seq 100, ack_seq=20) to B before A sends the ACK.

Comment: RFC 793, the specification for TCP. All packets except for the initial SYN have the ACK flag set.

Comment: I wrote some codes to test your waying: `The receiver processes the acknowledgement number and the data independently`, I establish a tcp connection between two hosts D and E, at first I send some packets with correct `seq` and `ack_seq` from Dto E, it is fine. The receiver processes the data(show them on the terminal). Then I send packets from D to E with correct `seq` but incorrect `ack_seq`, according to your theory, the receiver E should process the packet data since `seq` is correct, but ignore the `ack_seq`. But the receiver doesn't process the packet data.

Comment: Is your theory wrong or there is something wrong with my program?  thanks!

Comment: Was the ack_seq too high or too low? If it acknowledged something that was never sent, the packet fails validity checking. Why don't you just read RFC 793, it explains the process that the receiver performs in excruciating detail.

Comment: ah, I finally find the problem, the ack_seq is too high, you meant if the ack_seq is low, then data packets can still be accepted. but if it is too high, it will never be accepted?